# Generate a random number if the number matched with the previous

Tags: c#, random

I want to create a random number with a text in front of it, and I don't want the system displaying a number twice. So, this is that the way that I did it:

```
Random _rand = new Random();

private void RandomNumberGenerator()
        {
            int random = _rand.Next(10000);
            string text = "TP0" + random;

            if (random.Equals(random))
            {
                _rand.Next();
            }

            else
            {
                random = _rand.Next(10000);
            }

            MessageBox.Show(text);
        }
```

I am not getting any displayed number twice (but I am not too sure, because I just close the program until it displayed the number 5 times (all of it are not the same number).

Is it possible from the above code to displaying a number twice with any chance?

Thank you.

Comment: `random.Equals(random)` wouldn't return always `true`? Why you used it?

Comment: Generate a sequence from 0 to 10000 then use [Fisher–Yates shuffle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher-Yates_shuffle)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EDITED to get rid of magic numbers and ensure sanity.

```
  Random _rand = new Random();
  HashSet<int> _taken = new HashSet<int>();
  object _syncRoot = new object();

  private int RandomNumberGenerator() {
    lock (_syncRoot) {
      const int MAX_NUMBER = 10000;
      if (_taken.Count == MAX_NUMBER) {
        throw new Exception("All possible numbers are already generated.");
      }

      int random = _rand.Next(MAX_NUMBER);
      while (_taken.Contains(random)) {
        random = (random + 1) % MAX_NUMBER;
      }
      _taken.Add(random);
      return random;
    }
  }
```

Comment: What if `(random + 1) % 10000` were generated 2 calls before? A single `_oldNumber` is not enough.

Comment: @L.B - I though the goal is not to have sequence of two numbers of the same value; updated to ensure uniqueness of all numbers in sequence

Comment: @OndrejSvejdar: what is the HashSet, lock and object? anyway, thanks for your answer :D

Comment: @Kaoru The lock and the object ensures atomicity if you want to use this random number generator from multiple threads. See http://msdn.microsoft.com//library/c5kehkcz.aspx

Comment: What will happen on the 10001st call to RandomNumberGenerator?

Comment: @dureuill - for the nitpickers; I've handled that state as well :)

Comment: A well deserved +1 then

Comment: Thank you for your answer @OndrejSvejdar, but I want to ask one more question, I already called that function on the constructor, but nothing shown, also I already tried `MessageBox.Show`, but it does not displayed anything.

Answer (score 1):

Soner Gonul is correct, random.Equals(random) is always going to be true I think.
You could work around it (roughly) by having another int variable which will become whatever the last number generated was, *then* when the function goes into it's next cycle have it reference the new random number variable against the one stored in your second variable, which is the previous random number. That's one way of doing it, I can try define that a little clearer in a minute if you don't understand

Comment: Welp, @OndrejSvejdar has written a much nicer actual example of what I was trying to say :p